# Asp.Net Mvc: Extending domain entities and creating interfaces to create your view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

```
/* Domain Entity */
public class Employee 
{
   //code here
}

/* View Model */
public class EmployeeViewModel : Employee, IEmployeeViewModel
{
   //Add any properties and method to implement IEmployeeViewModel
}

public interface IEmployeeViewModel
{
   //Expose and define any properties or methods that its corresponding view(s) may need
}

// IEmployeeViewModel.ascx binds to a IEmployeeViewModel
```

What do you think with the above implementation? I have never seen an asp.net mvc sample project implement their view models and views in this fashion and I dont know why. Instead, view model classes are simple objects that map to domain entities and properties.

Answer (score 0):

`EmployeeViewMOdel : Employee` couples your ViewModel to your domain.

That defeats the entire purpose of having decoupled UI layers.

Comment: Yes, it does... but what abou having a ViewModel where you use a Model property in it?  It couples in the same way. Or a ViewModel need to be of pure .NET types repeating the onces you have in the model. I don't think so.